# How to merge two accounts with opportunity record?

Tags: apex

I have created two account Test1 and Test2.
Test1 has an opportunity record. 
and Test2 is survivor account.
when I am merging both account I am  getting an error "Cannot delete account with related opportunities."

Comment: You can merge accounts if you’re an administrator, the account owner, or a user above the account owner in the role hierarchy and you have the appropriate user permissions (”Delete” on accounts and “Edit” on related objects, such as opportunities and cases).